# Unresolved symbols in ASP.Net MVC 5 - OWIN Startup.Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm currently manually migrating a ASP.Net MVC 4 project to ASP.Net MVC 5 + WebAPI 2 and I'm struggling to get my OWIN Startup.Auth class even to compile.

Can anyone point me to the NUGET packages that should resolve the symbols marked in red in the picture below?

**UPDATE**: Resolved by installing the packages mentioned by Dunken. But I also had to change:

```
AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
```

to

```
AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following packages:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
```